# fastest way to count the number of occurences of a character in a numpy.chararray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Pythonists,

What is the fastest way to count the occurrence of a character in a `numpy.character` array.

I am doing the following:

```
In [59]: for i in range(10):
...:     m = input("Enter A or B: ")
...:     rr[0][i] = m
...:     
Enter A or B: B
Enter A or B: B
Enter A or B: B
Enter A or B: A
Enter A or B: B
Enter A or B: A
Enter A or B: A
Enter A or B: A
Enter A or B: B
Enter A or B: A

In [60]: rr
Out[60]: 
chararray([['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A']],
          dtype='<U1')

In [61]: %timeit a = rr.count('A')
12.5 µs ± 206 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [62]: %timeit d = len(a[a.nonzero()])
3.03 µs ± 54.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I believe there must be a better way to achieve this with speed and elegance.

Comment: Would all elements in the chararray be single characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`It's better to stick to regular NumPy arrays over the chararrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html#numpy.chararray) :

> Note:
>
> The chararray class exists for backwards compatibility with
>   Numarray, it is not recommended for new development. Starting from
>   numpy 1.4, if one needs arrays of strings, it is recommended to use
>   arrays of dtype object_, string_ or unicode_, and use the free
>   functions in the numpy.char module for fast vectorized string
>   operations.

Going with the regular arrays, let's propose two approaches.

**Approach #1**

We could use [`np.count_nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) to count the `True` ones after comparison against the search element : `'A'` -

```
np.count_nonzero(rr=='A')
```

**Approach #2**

With the `chararray` holding single character elements only, we could optimize a lot better by viewing into it with `uint8` dtype and then comparing and counting. The counting would be much faster, as we would be working with numeric data. The implementation would be -

```
np.count_nonzero(rr.view(np.uint8)==ord('A'))
```

On `Python 2.x`, it would be -

```
np.count_nonzero(np.array(rr.view(np.uint8))==ord('A'))
```

---

**Timings**

Timings on original sample data and scaled to `10,000x` scaled ones -

```
# Original sample data
In [10]: rr
Out[10]: array(['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A'], dtype='<U1')

# @Nils Werner's soln
In [14]: %timeit np.sum(rr == 'A')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.86 µs per loop

# Approach #1 from this post
In [13]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(rr=='A')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 µs per loop

# Approach #2 from this post
In [40]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(rr.view(np.uint8)==ord('A'))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 µs per loop

# Original sample data scaled by 10,000x
In [16]: rr = np.repeat(rr,10000)

# @Nils Werner's soln
In [18]: %timeit np.sum(rr == 'A')
1000 loops, best of 3: 734 µs per loop

# Approach #1 from this post
In [17]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(rr=='A')
1000 loops, best of 3: 659 µs per loop

# Approach #2 from this post
In [24]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(rr.view(np.uint8)==ord('A'))
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. I am going with `numpy.count_nonzero()`

Comment: Can you mention that `chararray` is deprecated in favor of regular `array`s? If you do that I can delete my answer altogether :-)

Comment: @NilsWerner Added. For the timing comparison, would be nice to have your solution, if you would like to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

[`chararray` is deprectated, use `array(..., dtype='<U1')` instead](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html). That being said you can do

```
r = np.array([['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A']])

%timeit numpy.sum(r == 'A')
# 4.82 µs ± 126 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```