# Apply function to each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am trying to apply the following function for each row in a dataframe. The dataframe looks as follows:

```
vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4
a      a       a      b           
b      b       a      b          
b      a       a      b
```

I am tring to generate a fourth column to sum the 'votes' of the other columns and produce the winner, as follows:

```
vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4 winner_columns
a      a       a      b           a
b      b       a      b           b 
b      a       a      b           draw
```

I have currently tried:

```
def winner(x):
    a = new_df.iloc[x].value_counts()['a']
    b = new_df.iloc[x].value_counts()['b']
    if a > b:
        y = 'a'
    elif a < b:
        y = 'b'
    else:
        y = 'draw'
    return y

df['winner_columns'].apply(winner)
```

However the whole column gets filled with draws. I assume is something with the way I have build the function but can't figure out what

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `axis=` parameter in the `df.apply()` method?

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DataFrame.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) and count non missing values by [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html), if only one use first column else `draw` in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1 = df.mode(axis=1)
print (df1)
   0    1
0  a  NaN
1  b  NaN
2  a    b

df['winner_columns'] = np.where(df1.count(axis=1).eq(1), df1[0], 'draw')
print (df)
  vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4 winner_columns
0      a      a      a      b              a
1      b      b      a      b              b
2      b      a      a      b           draw
```

Your solution is possible change:

```
def winner(x):
    s = x.value_counts()
    a = s['a']
    b = s['b']
    if a > b:
        y = 'a'
    elif a < b:
        y = 'b'
    else:
        y = 'draw'
    return y

df['winner_columns'] = df.apply(winner,axis=1)
print (df)
  vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4 winner_columns
0      a      a      a      b              a
1      b      b      a      b              b
2      b      a      a      b           draw
```

Comment: Could you help me adjust this for if there was more than 2 options as a winner? for example if there was 4 or 5 as potential voting choices?

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that your DataFrame contains sometimes
a letter followed by a dot.

So to look for solely `'a'` or `'b'` you have to replace these dots
with an empty string, something like:

```
df.replace('\.', '', regex=True)
```

Another problem, which didin't surface in your case, is that a row can
contain **only** `'a'` or `'b'` and your code should be resistant to
**absence** of particular result in such a source row.

To make your function resistant to such cases, change it to:

```
def winner(row):
    vc = row.value_counts()
    a = vc.get('a', 0)
    b = vc.get('b', 0)
    if a > b: return 'a'
    elif a < b: return 'b'
    else: return 'draw'
```

Then you can apply your function, but if you want to apply it to each
**row** (not column), you should pass *axis=1*.

So, to sum up, change your code to:

```
df['winner_columns'] = df.replace('\.', '', regex=True).apply(winner, axis=1)
```

The result, for your sample data, is:

```
  vote_1 vote_2 vote_3 vote_4 winner_columns
0     a.     a.     a.      b              a
1     b.     b.      a      b              b
2     b.     a.      a      b           draw
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.sum()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html?highlight=sum#numpy.sum) for counting the votes, then you save in a list the winners, finally you add into dataframe.

```
numpy_votes = dataframe_votes.to_numpy()    
winner_columns = []
for i in numpy_votes:
  if np.sum(i == 'a') < np.sum(i == 'b'):
     winner_columns.append('b')
  elif np.sum(i == 'a') > np.sum(i == 'b'):
     winner_columns.append('a')
  else:
     winner_columns.append('draw')
    
dataframe_votes['winner_columns'] = winner_columns
```

Using .sum() method is the fastest way to count elements inside arrays according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52145157/fastest-way-to-count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-character-in-a-numpy-chararra) answer.

Output:

```
    vote_1  vote_2  vote_3  vote_4  winner_columns
0   a        a         a        b       a
1   b        b         a        b       b
2   b        a         a        b       draw
```